# $a^5+b^5=c^5+d^5$ and polynomial identities

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

No nontrivial integer solutions to $$ a^5+b^5=c^5+d^5 \qquad (1)$$ are known.

(1) has infinitely many solutions in an extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ 
(root of $9-15x+37x^2 $ ) resulting
from a genus 0 curve and the identity
$$ (-2 y - 1)^5 + (x + \frac{1}{3} y - 1)^5- (\frac{1}{3} y - 1)^5 - (x - 2 y - 1)^5 = $$
$$ \left(-\frac{35}{81}\right) \cdot y \cdot (-3 x + 5 y + 6) \cdot x \cdot (9 x^{2} - 15 x y + 37 y^{2} - 18 x + 30 y + 18)$$

I wonder if some similar genus 0 or 1 curve might have points over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4 \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, where $\deg(p_i)=1$ and the $p_i^2$
are distinct.

Let $P=p_1^5+p_2^5-p_3^5-p_4^5$.

Q1. Can $P$ have an irreducible factor of degree 3?

Q2. Is there a reason for all degree 2 factors of $P$ to not have infinitely many
rational points over $\mathbb{Q}$?

I couldn't solve Q1 by equating coefficients (couldn't solve the system).

Found a lot of genus 0 factors, but all of them didn't have rational points
and linear factors gave only trivial solutions.

Comment: That genus-zero parametrization gets rediscovered often.
It's actually defined over ${\bf Q}$ but alas has no rational
points, being birational with the conic $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$.
The nice way to see it is to intersect the quintic surface
$a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5=0$ with the line $a+b+c+d=0$: the resulting
quintic curve decomposes into three lines
$a+b=c+d=0$, $a+c=d+b=0$, $a+d=b+c=0$,
and a residual conic with $S_4$ symmetry
that has no rational or even real roots but does work over
${\bf Q}(i)$ and various other totally imaginary number fields.
