# On Solving $a^k+nb^k = c^k+nd^k$, especially $k = 5$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given an initial integer solution to,

$a^k+mb^k = c^k+md^k\tag{1}$

it's quite easy to find subsequent ones for $ k = 2,3,4$ that are *primitive*, i.e. $GCD(a,b,c,d) = 1$. (In fact, for $k=2,3$, there are polynomial parameterizations for any $m$.)

I was wondering about $k>4$. For example, for,

$a^5+2b^5 = c^5+2d^5\tag{2}$

we have $a,b,c,d = 1355,526,1685,-1349$. Can we use this initial solution to find an infinite more primitive ones to $(2)$?

***P.S.*** We can reformulate $(2)$ as,

$(p+q)^5+(p-q)^5 = 2(r+s)^5+2(r-s)^5\tag{3}$

$p(p^4+10p^2q^2+5q^4) = 2r(r^4+10r^2s^2+5s^4)\tag{4}$

though I don't know if that helps.

Comment: Isn't there a theorem that a surface of general type
has only finitely many automorphisms?  (There might still be a curve of genus $0$ or $1$ that contains your point and infinitely many others, but this would still not handle a *general* solution of $a^5+2b^5=c^5+2d^5$.)

Comment: Ok, maybe not a general solution, but I'll be happy with any _special_ one that yields this point and infinitely many others. I know that Choudhry gave such for $x_1^5+x_2^5+2x_3^5 = y_1^5+y_2^5+2y_3^5$.

Comment: One approach is to try to find curve similar to this:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126852/a5b5-c5d5-and-polynomial-identities

Comment: P.S. I should have written "finitely many automorphisms 
*and no self-maps of degree greater than 1*".  Also, the identity
$$1355^5 + 2 \cdot 526^5 = 1685^5 − 2 \cdot 1349^5$$ is somewhat surprising
with coefficients this small compared to the variables $a,b,c,d$; has it been observed before?

Comment: After my post in another mathforum back in 2009, James Waldby was kind enough to generate positive [solutions](http://pat7.com/jp/s515-10007-t) to $x_1^5+x_2^5+\dots+x_5^5 = z^5$. I noticed that one also obeyed the relation discussed here. Incidentally, after one of my other posts, Choudhry and Wroblewski found that $a^5+b^5+(-a-b)^5 = c^5+d^5+(-c-d)^5$ has an infinite number of primitive solutions. I believe its coming out in a paper soon.

Comment: By the way, Waldby's database at http://pat7.com/jp/s515-10007-t has $z<10^4$. Also I checked Seiji Tomita's [_database_](http://www3.alpha-net.ne.jp/users/fermat/533e.html) of $x_1^5+x_2^5+x_3^5 = y_1^5+y_2^5+y_3^5$ with $x_i, y_i < 10^4$. Out of 3007 positive solutions, absolutely none obeyed the relation discussed in this post. Hmm.